# Python 3.X exec + compile - pass command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

I see answers on how to pass command line arguments to exec but not if compile is nestled inside.

Provided with the code:

```
filename = 'C:\\temp\\script.py'
exec(compile(open(filename).read(),filename, 'exec'))
```

**How can I pass command line arguments or input to the calling code?**

---

Additional context (you don't have to read):

A program called Blender has a built-in text editor / interpreter. And I want to inject code using the statement above. I tried using exec by itself without success. That's why I need exec and compile together. Code structure looks like this:

```
import bpy

# Create a new material
mat_ref = bpy.data.materials.new("Mat for joined object")

# Use shader nodes to render the material
mat_ref.use_nodes = True
nodes = mat_ref.node_tree.nodes

# Start from fresh state
mat_ref.node_tree.links.clear()
mat_ref.node_tree.nodes.clear()

# Create the Shader nodes
node_diffuse = nodes.new( type = 'ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse' )
node_matoutput = nodes.new( type = 'ShaderNodeOutputMaterial' )
node_voronoi = nodes.new( type = 'ShaderNodeTexVoronoi' )

# Link the shader nodes
mat_ref.node_tree.links.new( node_diffuse.outputs['BSDF'], node_matoutput.inputs['Surface'] )
mat_ref.node_tree.links.new( node_voronoi.outputs['Distance'], node_matoutput.inputs['Displacement'] )

# Change properties of shader nodes
mat_ref.node_tree.nodes["Voronoi Texture"].inputs[2].default_value = 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is the best way to achieve your actual goal - you may have a bit of an XY problem here.

However, the question is valid and the answer straightforward. `exec()` will execute your code in the current context, so whatever your current arguments are in the calling script will be the arguments available to the called script.

So, if `script.py` is:

```
import sys

print('Script: ', sys.argv[0])

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print('Argument(s): ', ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

And you run this `compile_exec.py`:

```
import sys

with open('script.py') as f:
    content = f.read()

compile(content, 'script.py', 'exec')

sys.argv[1:] = ['Hello', 'world']  # overriding any other arguments, careful

exec(content)
```

That will output:

```
Script:  < path to your script >\compile_exec.py
Argument(s):  Hello world
```

Or, as the oneliner you asked about:

```
import sys

sys.argv[1:] = ['Hello', 'world']
exec(compile(open('script.py').read(), 'script.py', 'exec'))
```